# How to get JList getSelectedValue() to return a Class Object?

Tags: java, jlist, jdialog

I am using a JList that contains Objects of Houses with addresses. The Houses are in a TreeMap (Not sure if that was the best choice) in a Neighborhood class. I am using Map.Entry and .entryset() to add the House values to a DefaultListModel, and then adding that to my JList. When clicking on a House object in the list, I want a JDialog to pop up with all of the house properties such as address, number of floors etc. My issue is when I use getSelectedValue() from the ListSelectionListener, it will only return either a String in the form of .toString() or a generic Object type. In my JDialog how can I get each House property in its own text field? I can't seem to just do house.getAddress() since it doesn't allow me to pass it as a House object. I have tried casting list.SelectedValue() to a House but I end up getting an error of "class java.util.TreeMap$Entry cannot be cast to class House". I have no issues accessing the properties when I print them from the Map, but once they're in the JList that's when I run into issues.

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question or something doesn't make sense. I'm still very new to Java and programming in general!

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for (Map.Entry<String, House> value : neighborhood.houses.entrySet()) {

 System.out.println(value);
 //System.out.println(value.getValue().getAddress()); //< This seems to work
 model.addElement(value);
}

JList list = new JList(model);
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
  if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
   System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue());
   House selectedObj = (House)list.getSelectedValue();
   HouseDialog houseDialog = new HouseDialog (selectedObj);
  }
 }
});
```

I get "class java.util.TreeMap$Entry cannot be cast to class House" as a result

Comment: You're adding the `Entry` to the `List` -> `model.addElement(value);`, maybe you meant to do `model.addElement(value.getValue());` instead?  `DefaultListModel` also supports generics, so you could further safe guard yourself by using `DefaultListModel<House> model = new DefaultListModel<>();` and `JList<House> list = new JList<>(model);`.  This would also mean that `list.getSelectedValue()` would return an instance of `House` so you won't need to cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `Map.Entry` to your `ListModel`...

```
for (Map.Entry<String, House> value : neighborhood.houses.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(value);
    model.addElement(value);
}
```

Maybe you meant to do `model.addElement(value.getValue());` instead?

What you should (also) do, is make use of the generic support of the `DefaultListModel` and `JList`.  This will provide you with compile time protection, meaning you can only add instances of `House` to your model and you don't need to cast the value when you retrieve it, for example...

```
DefaultListModel<House> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, House> value : neighborhood.houses.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(value);
    model.addElement(value.getValue());
}

JList<House> list = new JList<>(model);
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue());
            House selectedObj = list.getSelectedValue();
            HouseDialog houseDialog = new HouseDialog(selectedObj);
        }
    }
});
```

This assumes you only want the `House` and not the `Map.Entry<String, House>`.  You could still make use of the `Map.Entry` if you wanted to following the same basic idea, just that you'd need to use `Map.Entry#getValue` to get the reference to to `House` before displaying it.

Comment: Changing DefaultListModel<House> model = new DefaultListModel<>(); and  JList<House> list = new JList<>(model); did the trick. Thank you so much!!!!!!!